# How can I get the source code to gnome-system-monitor and use it in my application?

Tags: python, application-development, quickly

I want to create a system monitor quite similar to gnome-system-monitor in ubuntu using python.

I have used quickly application for the GUI and now i want to show the cpu history as shown by the system monitor , I want to know where I can get the source code to the system monitor and how to use it in my application.

Answer (score 5):

The source code for the System Monitor can be acquired by opening a terminal and entering:

```
apt-get source gnome-system-monitor
```

Unfortunately it is written in C. You cannot extend it with Python and Quickly.

Answer (score 1):

A good reference for that would be the CPUMeter screenlet.  You'd have to handle saving the data though.

`sudo apt-get install screenlets-pack-all`

On my system it's located here:
`/usr/share/screenlets/screenlets-pack-all/CPUMeter/CPUMeterScreenlet.py`

Tested on 12.04